# RuntimeBinderException occured in use dynamic keyword

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, dynamic

I have a silverlight 5 application running in Out-Of-Browser mode and with elevated trust mode. I have added a button with the below mentioned click handler code.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"))
        {
            shell.Run(@"C:\windows\notepad.exe");
        }
    }
```

Upon executing the application and clicking on the button, I am getting a RuntimeBinderException stating

'object' does not contain a definition for 'Run'
I found a similar question posted here but no one has provided a solution for the same. Hence reposting the question.

Please help.